# When does popstate fire?

Tags: javascript, html

I put all of my code in $(document).ready as per norm, but should I put my 'popstate' listener at the very end of this code too?  Or does it matter?

Comment: you will have to excuse me but what is popstate?

Comment: Hopefully you're aware that `onpopstate` is not supported in all browers: http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Comment: used2could: In Chrome popstate is triggered when the page first loads as well (I haven't tested in Firefox).

Comment: You have two separate questions in your post (placement, impact), and a third in the title (order).  It looks like some answers have addressed less than all three questions.  Can you clarify what it is you're after?  Personally I find the order events are fired in to be the critical piece (and especially if different browsers have a different order or set of circumstances when the popstate event will even fire at all, as it appears may be the case).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really matter, and since it's an event, can even be done before your `ready` method. The only thing needing to be placed inside `document ready` is code interacting with the DOM. Everything else doesn't (and possibly shouldn't) be placed in document ready.

Example:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    // binding this event can be done anywhere, 
    // but shouldn't be inside document ready
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // DOM manipulation and other stuff
});
```

Now when popstate actually is triggered is a lot different than when it is bound. According to the Mozilla doc:

> > A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

Comment: one exception: if you're using document.ready to alias `jQuery` to `$` (e.x. `jQuery(function($){...code...});`) you will want to use an anonymous function to do the aliasing: `(function($){...code...})(jQuery);`

Comment: Agreed, although I am not aware of anyone that uses document ready for that purpose

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by performing a browser action, such as clicking on the back button (or calling `history.back()` in JavaScript), when navigating between two history entries for the same document.

Comment: I don't think this is still true: "It changes the current history entry to that of the last page the user visited or, if history.pushState() has been used to add a history entry to the history stack, that history entry is used instead". I take that to mean pushState() triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused, because popstate was firing on every page load (I use chrome).

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate:

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
>   Firefox doesn't.

So in chrome (and apparently safari), the jquery ready method will execute, followed by the popstate event.
i.e. it doesn't matter if you attach the event within ready (or body.onload for that matter), the popstate event will happen after your ready method is complete.

In firefox (16.0.1) the popstate event does not fire on page loads (I can't test IE 10).

Comment: In Chrome (45.0.2454.93) it doesn't fire on page load anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a key to the state every time you push to history or replacing the state, and check for it on the popstate event, if you don't use the state at all you can simply push {} as state and quit the pop state in case the event.state is null.